# VSCode Microsoft extensions "Black Formatter" and "Pylint" failing to initialise "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lsp_jsonrpc'"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to install the pylint and black formatter extensions on VSCode, but the services fail to initialise. Both give an error like this

```
2023-08-18 15:25:55.613 [info] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\djames\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.black-formatter- 
2023.4.1\bundled\tool\lsp_server.py", line 38, in <module>
import lsp_jsonrpc as jsonrpc
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lsp_jsonrpc'
```

In my json file I have the line which points to a 3.10 interpreter

```
"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "C:\\Users\\djames\\Devel\\Python\\Python310\\python.exe",
```

and with this interpreter, I tried

```
python -m pip install python-lsp_jsonrpc
```

which installed successfully but did not fix the issue.

My version of VSCode is 1.81.1. I am on Windows 10. My Python3.10 was installed using an embeddable zip file.

Comment: In the end I abandoned the embedded package and installed via the windows installer and the problem went away. But I will try your solution on an embedded package and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the python version displayed in the lower right corner of the interface is `python 3.10`, if not, click and select `Use Python From "python.defaultInterpreterPath" setting`.

[image]

Also make sure your `python-lsp_jsonrpc` is installed in `python 3.10`.